# Sendgrid on PHPLIST

Tags: sendgrid, phplist

I have been trying to integrate sendGrid with PHPList. Sad I couldn't find any latest article / document on same.

I tried changing `config/config.php` file. here is the code [edits],

```
define('PHPMAILERHOST', 'smtp.sendgrid.net');
$phpmailer_smtpuser = 'uname';
$phpmailer_smtppassword = 'pass';
define("PHPMAILER_SECURE",'tls');

## you can set this to send out via a different SMTP port
define('PHPMAILERPORT', 587);
```

I also tried to edit `setupdir/admin/phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php`. Here is how it looks [changed lines],

```
public $Host = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';
public $Port = 587;
public $Helo = '';
public $SMTPSecure = 'tsl';
public $SMTPAutoTLS = true;
public $SMTPAuth = true;
public $Username = 'myusername';
public $Password = 'mypass';
```

I tried both but its not working. Can someone point me to exact place I need to change code?

Thanks,

Comment: Not familiar with php list, but port 465 is for SSL mailing in SendGrid

Comment: Seems like 587 is ok. https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Email_Infrastructure/smtp_ports.html

Comment: It is, if your not using SSL

Comment: yes. tsl is not ssl, right?  I am not sure.

Comment: What error message or result are you seeing? what does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You've got `TSL` in the config instead of `TLS`.